Error while building Inlie keyboard in aiogram 3.8.0
Code:
    @dp.message(F.photo)
async def forward(message: Message):
    buttons = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data='like')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data='dislike')]
    ]
    await message.send_copy(admin, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=buttons))
    await message.answer("Хохма отправленна админу")
    print(bot.get_chat(message.from_user.id))

Error:
[InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data='like')],
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BaseModel.init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Во-первых, вопрос должен быть на русском языке, а во-вторых, читайте актуальную документацию https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/inline_keyboard_button.html
